# How to add Attribute to a clicked element in a directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have created a custom directive and i need to add an `id` attribute to the clicked element in that directive.

Here is the code i did:

```
app.directive('newDiv', ['$window', function($window){
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  link: function(scope, element, attr) {
   console.log(attr);
   element.bind('click', function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName == "IMG"){
    }
  });
 },
 transclude: true,
 template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
 };
}]);
```

Through research, i found to use `$set` on `attr` but i'm not getting how to `$set` on a clicked element.

I need to add an `id` attribute to the clicked element only if the clicked image is `img` tag.